# PowerBI - Multiple CSV Dataload fail / no error

Tags: csv, powerbi

I have a problem with loading multiple CSV files in to powerBI. I have done this several times before without any problems.

In this situation I am loading in 2 CSV files (this will increase montly by one extra file) of both 5 columns (Date - Number - Number - Number - Number). I load them from the same file on my PC.

In my query editor it says that there are 2 files in the 'source' step, both of BINARY content. In the step 'navigation which comes after the 'source' step it only says it is loading in 1 of the 2 files. This means it is ignoring 1 file completely. On top of that PowerBI gives me no error whatsoever.

Both files have the same data setup.

Hope to hear something from you soon.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the "folder" connector? it will allow it to load all the files in a folder. Right now, probably you are using the CSV source, which will load a specified file (only one)

Comment: Yes, I am using the folder connector. I looked for an answer online and found multiple people with the same problem. They say it is a problem in PowerBI itself and an update will follow this march in which the bug will be fixed.

Comment: I was not aware of that, let's hope the patch comes out soon.